# Got problem when uploading the html into the webview in iphone sdk

Tags: html, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:loadUrl]];

 NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
 NSMutableString *returnString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSString *absString = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"footer" ofType:@"png"];
 NSURL *footerURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:absString];
    NSString* appendString=@"";
 appendString = [appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<body>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<table background='footer.png' width='320' height='45' style='background-repeat:no-repeat'>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<tr>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<td align='left' width='57' height='31' style='padding: 6px 0 0 0' ><a href='/map/'><img src='details_Back.png'/></a></td>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<td align='left' valign='middle' style='padding: 0 0 0 65px; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:21px ; font-weight:bold ; color:#FFF'>Details</td>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"</tr>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"</table>"];

 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<br>"];
 //returnString = [returnString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<body>" withString:appendString];
 [returnString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<body>"
          withString:appendString
          options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
            range:NSMakeRange(0, [returnString length])];

 [returnString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"footer.png"
          withString:[footerURL absoluteString]
          options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
            range:NSMakeRange(0, [returnString length])];

 printf("\n return string :%s",[returnString UTF8String]);
 [myWebView loadHTMLString:returnString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc.api.abcdef.com"]];
```

here in the above code the footer.png and details_back.png are the local images stored in my resource folder.

Here the problem is I am gettin the background image from the server link I had passed to the webview as baseurl but the images footer.png and details_back.png which were stored in resource is not displayed.

if I use the resource bundle as the baseurl then I am not displayed the background image from the server link.

Can anyone please give me the suggestions to get rid of rid of this problem.

thanks to all guy's,
Monish.

Comment: May I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/karelia/KSHTMLWriter for building your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should NSMutableString when building a string for performance reason.

The image src path in your html need the full URL path to the resource bundle.  To get the URL path of the resource do the following:

```
    NSString *footerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                        pathForResource:@"footer" 
                        ofType:@"png"];
NSURL *footerURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:footerPath];
```

Once you get the image url and build your custom body, you will replace footer.png with the full url of the image:

```
    [myCustomBody replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"footer.png"
                              withString:[footerURL absoluteString]
                                 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, [myCustomBody length])];
```

Comment: @Black Frog:I tried as per your suggestion eventhough I am not getting the local images to be displayed.Can u please help me with other ideas.

Comment: I tested the code before I posted it. Posted a copy of your code and I will take a look at it.

Comment: I had edited the code please check it where I had done the mistake.

Comment: Monish, please write the footer URL to console:  NSLo(@"Footer URL: %@", [footerURL absoluteString]); and post it here.  I would like to see what you have.

Comment: Footer URL: file://localhost/Users/kishorebabub/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/4.2/Applications/CA1946D9-7700-4175-9143-0D8318B5C32B/ParkingAreaLocator.app/footer.png

Comment: That path is correct. I am going to create a simple and post it for you see.

Comment: I created a simple project that replace the Google News logo with my own.  I have placed a copy in my DropBox here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17348969/BlackFrogLogo.zip 
You have to make sure you set the baseURL to nil when you -loadHTMLString in the UIWebView.  Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: @Black frog:I saw the code in the zip file but for  me the base url should not be nil.There I should keep the client url mandatorily.Any ideas pls?

Comment: Hey I got the images my base url had the spelling mistake compared to the actual one.Anyone thanks for ur help and ur code I learnt many things from ur code and suggestions.+1 for u my friend.

Answer (score 0):

If the only consequence of using resource bundle as the base url is a lack of background image you could try replace its href property just like you did with the `<body>` tag.